# Python import - multi-level import doesn't always work

Tags: python, boto, python-import

I've seen this behavior in other cases so I don't believe it's `boto` specific, but I tagged this question as `boto` since this is where I saw the problem most recently.  When I do the following, it works in certain environments but not all:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3_conn = boto.s3.connection.S3Connection()
```

Some environments allow for this, but others give back this exception:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'`

But, the following works in all environments (or at least the few cases that I have):

```
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
>>> s3_conn = S3Connection(access_key_id,secret_access_key)
```

I've seen this with other libraries as well, not just with `boto`.  Can anyone shed some light onto what is happening behind the scenes that causes the first case to not always work?

Comment: Note that [`\boto\s3\__init__.py`](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/s3/__init__.py) doesn't include `import connection`

Comment: That makes sense for the cases where the exception comes up, but then why would my first case ever succeed?

Comment: Good question; can you be more specific than *some environments*?

Comment: That would probably help, wouldn't it?  Duh!  I'm having success with `from x import y` in both of the following setups, but the direct `import x` version is succeeding with python 2.6 in Red Hat 4.1.2-42 but failing in python 2.7.5 with Red Hat 4.4.7-3.

Comment: A possibly-relevant change (see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.7.html#other-language-changes): *"The import statement will no longer try an absolute import if a relative import fails."*

Comment: That'd do it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Doing an import like

```
>>> import boto
```

gives you the `boto` package itself. None of the submodules will be imported with this statement, unless they're imported explicitly by `boto`. If they were already imported earlier, they are available with this import as well.

```
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
```

on the other hand will import all submodules successively.

Btw:

```
>>> import boto
>>> s3_conn = boto.connect_s3
```

would also help to resolve this particular issue for you.